# how to test an api with array on postman

Tags: rest, api, postman

All the api used in the application have a common end point : `https://m.companyname.com/application/svcwebservice.php`

The json has nested arrays and the response looks like this:

```
[{
    "usertype": [{
        "id": "1",
        "type": "Service Manager (Admin)",
        "description": "Service Manager (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "Customer Relations Executive",
        "description": "Customer Relations Executive"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "Service Advisor",
        "description": "Service Advisor"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "type": "Accountant (Admin)",
        "description": "Accountant (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "type": "Technician\/Mechanic",
        "description": "Technician\/Mechanic"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "type": "Sales Manager (Admin)",
        "description": "Sales Manager (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "type": "Sales Consultant",
        "description": "Sales Consultant"
    }, {
        "id": "8",
        "type": "Receptionist",
        "description": "Receptionist"
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "type": "Implant (Admin)",
        "description": "Implant (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "10",
        "type": "Vice President \/ General Manager - Sales (Admin)",
        "description": "Vice President \/ General Manager - Sales (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "type": "Group Manager (Admin)",
        "description": "Group Manager (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "13",
        "type": "Coordinator",
        "description": "Coordinator"
    }, {
        "id": "14",
        "type": "Customer Relations Manager (Admin)",
        "description": "Customer Relations Manager (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "15",
        "type": "Receptionist",
        "description": "Receptionist"
    }, {
        "id": "16",
        "type": "Vice President \/ General Manager - Service (Admin)",
        "description": "Vice President \/ General Manager - Service (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "17",
        "type": "Principal (Admin)",
        "description": "Principal (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "18",
        "type": "CEO (Admin)",
        "description": "CEO (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "19",
        "type": "COO (Admin)",
        "description": "COO (Admin)"
    }, {
        "id": "20",
        "type": "Insurane Admin",
        "description": "Insurane Admin"
    }]
}]
```

And payload is: requesttype: "getusertypes"

The same api endpoint gives following response for another payload like:

```
[{
    "cards": [{
        "average_inv_amount": "26",
        "on_time_checkin": "100.00%",
        "ontime_pickup_percentage": "81.89%",
        "average_distance": "5.5",
        "cust_rating": "4.2",
        "total_vehicle": "4"
    }]
}, {
    "pickup_details": [{
        "name": "Awaiting",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "Active Pickup",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "Not Checked in",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "Checked In",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "Picked Up Today",
        "value": "1"
    }]
}, {
    "drop_details": [{
        "name": "Awaiting",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "To Service Centre",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "To Customer",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "Active Dropoff ",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "Delivered Today",
        "value": "0"
    }]
}, {
    "notification": [{
        "queue_paused_pickup": "0",
        "queue_paused_dropoff": "0",
        "not_checkedin": "1",
        "queue_cancelled": "2",
        "queue_rescheduled": "0",
        "queue_mishaps": "0"
    }]
}, {
    "prepaid": [{
        "pre_paid": "-250",
        "credit_limit": "10000",
        "show_add_credit": "1",
        "allow_booking": "1"
    }]
}]
```

and so on.

***Question:***

How am i supposed to test this using postman?

Comment: What do you mean by *payload*? a request body?

Comment: payload that i get in developer tool

Comment: Could you please add that to the question, it's unclear to me - when you get a payload in the developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to test.

First parse your response with 
`var jsonData = pm.response.json();`

You can access themy by indexing like

```
pm.test("Your test name", function() {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    //For Entry 4
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].usertype[3].id).to.eql("4");
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].usertype[3].type).to.eql("Accountant (Admin)");
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].usertype[3].description).to.eql("Accountant (Admin)");
});
```

Or iterate over them by using for-loops. But it depends strong on your test-case.